# I Keep Getting DIfferent Large Numbers When Trimming SSD

Tags: ssd, trim

Each time I type the command "sudo fstrim / -v", I keep getting large numbers like 9 digits. It should say 0, since I haven't deleted anything? Are my deleted files actually trimmed?

- Blossom